# SQL count on large recordsets with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

So I think I understand the idea of querying the sys.partitions to get a **total** count on a table.

`SELECT SUM(rows) FROM sys.partitions WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.myTable')
  AND index_id IN (0,1);`

but how would I add conditions to the table I'm counting from?

E.g. `MyTable WHERE communityID = 123`

A generic SQL count(*) takes around 4-8 seconds to run so clearly isn't the solution.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Presumably if you have separate partitions you have a large number of rows, so invoking a `LIKE` is going to be very expensive.

Comment: Like was probably a bad example, I have a table of several million invite codes for various communities I need to specify the ID of the community when counting the invites.

Comment: Since you do not seem to be satisfied with the answers so far, maybe you should rephrase your question and also provide `table definition data`, `scripts for generating indexes` and `execution plan` taken by your query(ies) because that are the points where you really can see why something is not as fast as you maybe want it to be.

Comment: And why won't an index on `communityID` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select count(*) from table where communityID=123
```

Comment: On a million plus records this is far too slow.

Comment: @chris But maybe it is only too slow because you do not have a proper index on `communityID`, 1 million records is not that much really...

Comment: This was true :) the index was fubar.

Answer (score 0):

There's no other way than querying the table directly:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.myTable WHERE UserName LIKE '%C%'
```

Comment: On a million plus records this is far too slow.

Comment: After your modified question i would suggest adding proper indexes (LIKE '%C%' will not use any indexes)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 SELECT COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM dbo.myTable WHERE UserName LIKE '%C%'
```